# global ajaxComplete event not triggering

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
        alert('i love kitties');
});
```

and on my page, I have a dropdown list bound to some jquery:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: myURL,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr)
    {
        alert('success!');
    }
 });
```

The ajax call runs fine, but the ajaxComplete method does not trigger. Any ideas why? Am I misinterpreting how ajaxComplete works?

Edit - some more information!

my code has a data: component, and when I remove one of the properties, it works. The code looks like this:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: myURL,
    type: "POST",
    data: { a: 1, b: 2},
    success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr)
    {
        alert('success!');
    }
 });
```

if I remove b from the data, it triggers the ajaxComplete. If I put b first, remove a, all other combinations, it does not trigger. It does not like b.

Comment: I assume you close the ajaxComplete bracket (and place a semi-colon) ... don't you? :P

Comment: I doubt this is the answer, but you forgot to end your ajaxComplete with a bracket and semicolon `);`

Comment: Cheers guys, bad copy and paste job! Fixed my question...:)

Comment: Looks fine over here - http://jsfiddle.net/bwsTr/3/

Comment: Thanks for the JSFiddle, back to the drawing board! I can't think why mine doesn't work, it's pretty much identical to the above code.

Comment: can you use fiddler or firebug to see if your ajax call is actually happening? does the "success!" get alerted? Is the ajax call coming from the same document object?

Comment: The call completes successfully, fiddler confirms it as well as the page updating. I have a dropdown list that has an event bound to it, which causes the $.ajax event to run. Is it possible to have more than one document object?

Comment: @SLC What does your `b` value *really* look like? Does it fail for any value in `b`? Is `b` the actual parameter name?

Comment: I've examined it further and found that the parameters are not relevent, when I removed b it caused the ajax request to have an error 500 because of a null reference exception. So when the server error 500'd, the ajaxComplete method ran. I didn't notice it was doing that at first... so now I am even more stumped as to why 200 OK would not run the Complete method!